# How to configure Prometheus to use AWS RDS PostgreSQL/MySQL as backing store?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus-operator

I am using prometheus-operator in Kubernetes and am using EBS volumes as backing store through VolumeClaimTemplates. I would like to instead use Amazon RDS PostgreSQL as a backing store so that I wouldn't have to worry about running out of storage and monitoring storage etc.

I came across remote storage adapters for InfluxDB, Graphite and OpenstDB [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/master/documentation/examples/remote_storage/remote_storage_adapter) but they don't have an adapter for PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Does anyone have any experience making prometheus backup samples to PostgreSQL/MySQL in production environments?

I came across prometheus-postgresql-adapter [here](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter) but am not sure how it will work with Amazon RDS. If you have any pointers to make it work with RDS, that too will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. Amazon RDS doesn't support that yet. The GitHub issue here says it all: https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter/issues/10.

Currently, if you want to use the [prometheus-postgresql-adapter](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter), you would need to run the [TimescaleDB](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb).